# Center multiple markers Google API v3

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I realize there are some examples out there of this but I can not make it work with my script. I realize you need to make a bounds but it does not want to work.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var infowindow;
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    downloadUrl("include/moredata.xml", function(data) {
      var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("name"), latlng);
       }
     });
  }

  function createMarker(name, latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: name});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;
  }

  function AutoCenter() {
    //  Create a new viewpoint bound
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    //  Go through each...
    $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
    });
    //  Fit these bounds to the map
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

</script>
```

At first I thought it was because I declared a center and zoom in my options, but even after taking those out, my map did not show up. Help please??? Thank you!

Comment: Is your question about the Marker or all the map is not shown?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted the map to center and zoom to the markers mapped. Right now the map should show up.

Comment: The first part sits in your `initialize function` the second part sits in your `for ( ... ) {` loop after you have defined the marker and the third part is inside your `$.each` loop replacing the `bounds.extend(marker.position)`. If you are having real problems I could post the code in a very succinct versions if you can give me a view of the xml.

Comment: Have you tried calling AutoCenter() right after the for loop in initialize()?

Comment: Clear as mud. Is this about setting bounds or getting a map to show?

Answer (score 0):

First set up an array:

```
var realMarkers = [];
```

Then push markers into the array:

```
var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("name"), latlng);
realMarkers.push(marker);
```

Then as you loop realMarkers:

```
bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
```

Comment: I'm sorry Martin, I am still confused as to where to put these pieces of code.